# Proces realtime data from Node.js in Python

Tags: python, node.js

I have a Node.js script collecting realtime data from motion sensors. I would like to pass each frame of data to a Python script and process the data there. I found a guide on how to send data to Python, but it just opens a lot of Python processes.

Is there a better way to send pass data from Node.js to Python to proces realtime data?

server.js

```
transFunc:function( component, parameters )
    {

        data2Python = Object.values(parameters).join()';

        const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        const process = spawn('python', ['./calculate_risk.py', data2Python]);
        process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            res.send(data.toString());
        });

    }
```

calculations.py

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

data = int(sys.argv[1]) # 3

def calculate_stuff(data):

    # do something with the data
    print(data)
    sys.stdout.flush()

calculate_stuff(data)
```

Comment: what on earth? this is no C#, change your brackets, its killing me.
Also you need to watch out, this might cause you with a bugs.
JS puts ";" after each line.

Comment: You could write the node.js data to a file and read it it with python. Keep the python process alive by checking if the file has changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to send pass data from Node.js to Python to proces realtime data?

You can use a python framework like [Flask](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask) and expose an API that will do the pandas part. It will return the result to the node client.